# Why can't my integration tests in Rider recognize App.Config file?

Tags: c#, rider

I have a C# project that I'm working on in Rider. Within this project I have an Integration Test project. When I go to run my integration tests, they fail because they call code that depends on information in the App.config file. I have made a linking reference in the integration test project to the App.config file from the main project. The integration tests still do not work. They throw ArgumentNullExceptions for any values that are stored in the App.config file. 
The main project runs fine and retrieves the values from the App.config file perfectly.
I have also tried rebuilding integration test project.

Whether I copy the App.config file over or make a linking reference to it, I get the same results.

Comment: What's the build action of the config in the test project set to?

Comment: The App.config file in the test project?

Comment: Yep, that's the one that the test will look for.

Comment: There is not a build action in it

Comment: Try setting the build action to `Content` and the Copy to Output directory setting to `Copy if Newer`. Do you tests pick up the settings?

Answer (score 0):

This may be resolved by adding the following to your .csproj file

```
<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" \>
    ...
    <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)/ReSharperTestRunner.dll.config" />
<Target/>
```

For some reason Rider isn't copying and loading it in its test runner.